# Filtering based on metadata using MEF and Autofac

Tags: dependency-injection, metadata, mef, autofac

I have a test MVC application that is using MEF as a plugin manager. In some external libraries I am exporting a bunch of controllers using MEF based off of a common interface:

```
 [Export(typeof(ICustomController)), PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
 [ExportMetadata("Feature", "Foo")]
 public class FooController : Controller, ICustomController
 {
 }
```

Now I have hooked this into autofac such that I can do this:

```
var controllers = container.GetServices<ICustomController>();
```

The problem I am running into is that I would like to filter on the metadata value. I know that autofac forces you to do that in the builder and not when you are calling GetServices so I have been digging around there. The problem is that the Export is being defined by MEF not autofac and it is generic. Here is what I want to do (note this does not work)

```
builder.RegisterType<ICustomController>().Exported(x=> x.As<ICustomController>().WithMetadata("Feature", "Foo"));
```

I realize that that is in a sense setting a new registration of the type. What I want it to do is realize that it already has a list of that type and when I ask for them only give me the ones that have the "Foo" feature in metadata.

Is this even possible? Is there a way to do it in MEF before the injection is handed off to autofac?